# Flatten problem or other?

Tags: list-manipulation

How to get the following list

`{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18}}`

from the following list

`{{1, 2, 3}, {{4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}, {10, 11, 12}, {{13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18}}}` ?

Different that `Partition[Flatten[list],3]`!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
lst = {{1, 2, 3}, {{4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}, {10, 11, 12}, {{13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18}}};
```

**Level**

```
Level[lst, {-2}]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15}, {16, 17,  18}}

**FlattenAt**

```
FlattenAt[lst, List /@ Range[2, Length[lst] , 2]]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15}, {16, 17,  18}}

**MapAt**

```
MapAt[Sequence @@ # &, lst, List /@ Range[2, Length[lst], 2]]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15}, {16, 17,  18}}

**Part assignment**

```
lst[[2 ;; ;; 2, 0]] = Sequence; lst
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15}, {16, 17,  18}}

**ReplacePart**

```
ReplacePart[lst, {_?EvenQ, 0} :> Sequence]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15}, {16, 17,  18}}

Answer (score 6):

Let:

```
l = {{1, 2, 3}, {{4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}, {10, 11, 12}, {{13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18}}
```

You can use `Cases` with its depth specification for this:

```
Cases[l,{_,_,_},\[Infinity]]
```

Alternatively, you can deactivate the terms of interest and flatten and reactivate:

```
Activate[Flatten[l /. {x_, y_, z_} -> Inactive[List][x, y, z]]]
```

Note: In this case, `Inactive[List]` is actually just being used as a convenient dummy function, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = 
   {{1, 2, 3},
   {{4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}},
   {10, 11, 12},
   {{13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18}}};
```

Using `Splice` (new in 12.1)

```
MapAt[Splice, Position[list, _?MatrixQ]] @ list
```

{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15}, {16, 17,
18}}

**Addendum**

As kglr commented a shorter solution would be

```
list /. x_?MatrixQ :> Splice[x]
```

Comment: also `list /. x_?MatrixQ :> Splice[x]` (+1)

Comment: Thank you, kglr, I addded your nice comment

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{1, 2, 3}, {{4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}, {10, 11, 12}, {{13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18}}};
```

Another way using `Reap`, `Scan` and `Sow`:

```
Reap[Scan[If[VectorQ[#], Sow[#]] &, list, ∞]][[2, 1]]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18}}

Answer (score 0):

Other possibilities:

```
lst/.{{a__},{b__}}:>Sequence[{a},{b}]

(* {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18}} *)
```

```
lst/.p:{{__},{__}}:>Delete[p,0]

(* {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{10,11,12},{13,14,15},{16,17,18}} *)
```